# Update the Label of a RichCombo according to Selection - CKEditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I have a custom RichCombo to allow Font selection. It goes through some data and creates its options, while the "special feature" consists of spans with the corresponding font-family set, instead of just plain text.

[image: Font Selector]

Now i want to change / update the `value` or `label` of this RichCombo box, on every change and from the outside as well. Basically, it should act exactly like the default Font selection box.

```
editor.ui.addRichCombo( 'FontFamily', {
    multiSelect : false,
    label: 'Schriftart',
    title: 'Schriftart',
    className:   'cke_format',
    panel: { css:[CKEDITOR.skin.getPath("editor")].concat(editor.config.contentsCss) },
    toolbar: 'font',
    init: function() {
        for (var i=0; i < allFonts.length; i++) {
            this.add(
                allFonts[i].class,
                '<span class="'+ allFonts[i].class +'">' + allFonts[i].label + '</span>',
                 allFonts[i].label
             );
        };
    },
    onClick: function(value) {
         updateFontCorrectly();
    }
}
```

Note that there is actually more code in place of the `updateFontCorrectly()` function.

I want to be able to do something like

```
this.setValue("Times New Roman");
```

(and instead pass through a variable), from inside the `onClick` function as well as from the outside, globally.

Theoretically, the code above works but breaks the box entirely after one use. Some class jQuery target (deep within the CKEditor source) seems to fail after using it once, and the RichCombo refuses to open.

I've stripped it down to

```
this._.value = "Times New Roman";
```

but this breaks after one use as well.

I have to be completely missing something here. How can i get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's really simple, as it turns out.

```
this.setValue(foo, "Text");
```

The only tricky part is that `foo` has to be a valid value, as in, it exists in `this._.items`.

If it's invalid, the richCombo will break. "Text" can be whatever you want it to be.